# How to avoid title bar at runtime theme setting in activity?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I want to port my app to android support library v7 revision 23.1.

For this purpose I have extended my theme from Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar as instructed in multitude of guides.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent=" Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar ">
```

I use dynamic theme setting at runtime in activity onCreate() method.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() started.");
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_default);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

The problem is that there is always old android TitleBar visible. I mean title bar, not action bar.
The problem only appears if I set the theme at runtime.
If I set it in manifest there is no title bar.
I guess this is some bug in support library, but, the question is, how to fix it?

Comment: So... you're seeing 2 action bars?

Comment: Are you talking about the old title bar from Android 2.x? Did you try to support only API 15 and above to see if it disappears?

Comment: @Dalmas Yes, the old 2.x title bar. No I did not. I run my test on a 2.3.5 physical device. One point to note is that if I set the theme in manifest the title bar disappears. So the problem is in setTheme() method.

Comment: I guess it's a bug in the support library, I would suggest you to hide the title bar manually with `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` (before calling `setContentView()`)

Comment: @Dalmas. Tnx. But calling requestWindowFeature() produces an exception even if called before setContentView().

Comment: As it turns out requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) must be called BEFORE super.onCreate().

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Dalmas in his comment requestWindowFeature() must be called. But it must me called in onCreate() method BEFORE super.onCreate().

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```